# How to check for PD and DP capabilities of a USB Type C port?

Tags: usb, usb-c

How can a user check for real the compliance and capabilities of USB Type C ports?

I can't find anywhere, including my notebook's manual, if my USB Type C port is PD capable, and, while the manual mentions it's display-port capable, there is no symbol on the devices' case. I have a PD-capable Baseus hub and I want to power it up so it stands all devices, but I'm afraid of frying my USB port by plugging a PD-charger on the hub.

I thus have looked for software like this: https://www.uwe-sieber.de/usbtreeview_e.html. I'm either unable to read properly the results or (more probably) it can't show port's capabilities.

Where to start?

Edit: for people still mentioning about the presence or absence of symbols beside the connector in the case, the port almost certainly support Thunderbolt, as a Thunderbolt hub shows up in HWINFO. Still, no thunderbolt indication on the case nor the manual.

Comment: No indication close to the port? Neither in the manual? Check the PC manufacturer with your PC reference, find the technical info about it? I'd also check in the BIOS if something different is indicated there.

Comment: If your manual and the port labelling does not mention it then it's reasonably safe to say that your port(s) likely do not support the features. That said a proper PD charger should not fry any ports. PD is a negotiated power connection and without negotiation the charger will stick at a "safe" 5V.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AIUI The power delivery and alternate modes aspect of a USB C port is somewhat seperate to the actual USB aspect. So frustrating as that is a USB device viewer won't generally provide useful information as to those aspects of the system.

That said, the whole point of USB power delivery negotiation is to *avoid* frying stuff. The risk from plugging in a charger from a reputable brand and seeing if the laptop starts charging should be minimal.

Comment: I ended up taking the risk. The port didn't support PD as the device ain't charging, but the devices plugged to the PD capable hub are now powered by the PD and disks won't die or keep disconnecting/reconnecting due to insufficient power from the notebook. And nothing go fried, after more than a year. That's pretty much what I really needed.

Answer (score -1):

One tricky solution would be to get help from StarTech, for example ;-)

They say [here](https://www.startech.com/en-us/blog/usb-power-delivery-explained):
If you are not 100% sure if your laptop can take advantage of USB PD, it is always best to check with your laptop’s manufacturer **or connect with our Technical Advisors to confirm.**

But I do confirm, **the best place is to check your manufacturer site for Technical Data about your laptop.**

Otherwise, if you can't find, you can call them [here](https://www.startech.com/en-us/support).

While telling them you'll to acquire [one of their hub](https://www.startech.com/en-us/universal-laptop-docking-stations?filter_dockfamily=multiport%2520adapter) and ask for compatibility.

If your laptop isn't in their list chances, are it won't work.

Ah, and just for reference if that can help, here is what's the indications that could/should be close to the USB ports:
[image]

Comment: This doesn’t answer the author’s question.

Comment: Uh, yes: "But I do confirm, the best place is to check your manufacturer site for Technical Data about your laptop." in BOLD ?

Comment: So the answer to the author’s question is to read the manual? The author likely thought of doing that and still asked the question. The time is nigh to improve this answer.

Comment: OP read the Manual and checked for indication on the laptop. No info. Apart going to the manufacturer's website, or any reliable website about his/her laptop... and AFAIK, no I don't think there's another solution. Of course you can plug in the USB PD and see if it works or not or burns ;-) That's a second solution, cf @plugwash.